# I cannot include Buefy in Vue3

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, buefy

someone knows how can I include Buefy in Vue3, becuause I am doing this (main.js) but I get an error:

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";
import Buefy from 'buefy';
import 'buefy/dist/buefy.css';

createApp(App)
  .use(store)
  .use(router)
  .use(Buefy)
  .mount("#app");
```

And the error is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Vue.prototype is undefined
```

Comment: That means it doesn't support Vue 3 - https://github.com/buefy/buefy/issues/2505

Comment: For others Vue library https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue/issues/3544

Answer (score 4):

Buefy support for Vue3 is still in the planning phase. I think that its going to a while.

https://github.com/buefy/buefy/issues/2505

As of 7 Dec 2020:
https://github.com/buefy/buefy/issues/2505#issuecomment-739899697

> Btw there is a new branch and I'll try to migrate other components to show you my main idea:
>
> - Typescript
> - Options API
>
> In my opinion the problem is not migrate all to Vue 3 but maintain two versions.
> Vue 3 is the future but official and not official libraries and frameworks (for example Nuxt) are not ready so I don't understand the really need at the moment.